# How to update environment variables without rebuilding the React app image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I'm building a dockerized React application and need to define some environment variables for API URLs. However, React inject those variables in the build phase, so I need to rebuild the whole image every time the environment changes. This slows down my pipeline, as I can't reuse the same app image for homologation and production.

I've searched for some patterns and I'm now using a JS config file to inject the environment on the fly, but it doesn't look very straightforward. Does someone know a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: If you're using env vars for build-time config, you can't. Also the fact that you're using different images in different environments, rather than promoting one asset, substantially reduces the value of any testing you're doing in them. See e.g. https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was searching exactly for an article like that, but I couldn't find any

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to accomplish is applying the principle of "build once, deploy many" to a ReactJS app.

The following article covers some of the available options to do that:
https://profinit.eu/en/blog/build-once-deploy-many-in-react-dynamic-configuration-properties/

> Build once, deploy many is an essential principle of software
> development. The main idea is to use the same bundle for all
> environments, from testing to production. This approach enables easy
> deployment and testability and is considered a fundamental principle
> of continuous delivery. It is also part of the twelve-factor
> methodology. As crucial as it is, it has not received significant
> support in the world of frontend development, and React is no
> exception.

The simplest solution provided by the article is based on an external configuration file.

External configuration file:

```
// public/config.js
// provided by the customer as a resource in the public folder, after compilation

const apiUrl = "http://api.myservice.com";
const env = "TST";
```

Website root (index.html):

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
<script>
  window.config = { apiUrl, env };
</script>
```

In other words, your bundled (built/compiled) app should import an external `config.js` file, and make them globally available using the `window` object.

The article goes on giving some more advanced and refined options, but the above should suffice for simple usecases.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently, then I published some packages: `@import-meta-env/*` to npm to solve the problem.

This plugin exposes environment variables on a special `import.meta.env` object (heavily inspired by Vite).

During production it will be statically **replaced with a placeholder** instead of current environment variables.

Thus we can run a script **anywhere** to populating files with environment variables from the system.

You can see more info at https://import-meta-env.org/ .

I also created a Docker example: https://github.com/runtime-env/import-meta-env/tree/main/packages/examples/docker-starter-example .

Hope this helps someone who needs it.

Comment: That's really interesting, I'll give it a try in a test project for sure. Thank you!

Comment: awesome! feel free to accept the answer if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the options presented by Ernest and pagliuca, you can also implement the Immutable Web Applications methodology presented in detail here: https://immutablewebapps.org/

Basically, separate static assets (which do not contain anything specific to the environment) and web application configuration (non-static) which varies from environment to environment and from deployment to deployment, using `index.html` as a configuration file.

An implementation advantage is that we can add version references to the static assets of the web application and set the environment variables. In the unlikely event that a browser attempts to load an outdated version of index.html, all features of the previous version will still be available and not corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Yes indeed this is a problem with environment variables. What you want to achieve can be done with a service that is commonly called "Remote Config" or "Config as a service - CaaS". This service notifies your application that some external data has changed. I would highly recommend [LaunchDarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) but you can always choose to build it on your own (not a fast solution though).
The only way to avoid multiple environment builds is by applying rules on the CaaS and modify the responses based on who requests (eg, based on the request's "Origin" header)

Comment: _"You can't avoid multiple environment builds.. This is a fact"_ - you _can_ (and probably _should_, promoting a single artefact is a much safer pattern than having a new build for every deployment environment), so it's not. This isn't the kind of thing feature flagging is for, either.

Comment: As long as you MUST use environment variables then you need a different build. You can't just add all environment-related data into one file and serve it on all environments

Comment: The OP clearly mentions "need to define some environment variables for API URLs".

Comment: You're right about Feature Flags, I'll update the answer

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - yes, if you're configuring at build time (with env vars or otherwise) then reconfiguring means rebuilding. But you _can_ extract all environment-related data to one file and _swap_ it between environments, for example, and the OP's current _"need"_ to define env vars is likely not actually a hard requirement.

Comment: Yeah probably that would work too!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this approach (extracting the env to a file). It works pretty well, but it's not very straightforward in my POV. Anyway it seems to be the best solution given how front-end works nowadays haha